# Using VLOOKUP but ignoring rows with specific text

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, office365

I have a table which contains a number of room bookings which includes start and end times. I have Column H state if the end time has passed.
I would like a VLOOKUP type formula to return the value of Sheet 2 column D on Today's date if column H is not equal to "ENDED".

In the example below i get the 1st incidence of today's booking in AB264 (Can & Venn). Once this session has ended at 10:00 AM i would like to display the next booking (Male Cath).

*(For reference B1 = TODAY() and H1 is the room number - both on Sheet 1)*

My existing formula returns the 1st match:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1&"|"&H1,Sheet2!B:G,3,FALSE),"--")
```

[image: Table on sheet 2]

I have a small amount of experience with VBA so if this can be done a better way (maybe even delete the ended rows) then i would be happy to try.

Comment: Using INDEX-MATCH.. you can try this link... https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2699-excel-vlookup-find-first-2nd-match.html

Comment: Did you try `FILTER()` function?

Comment: @Harun24hr i have tried to filter onto a 3rd sheet but i can't work out how to get rid of all the excess data underneath. =FILTER(Sheet2!A:F, Sheet2!G:G <>"ENDED","") It just gives me rows full of unfilled data. (e,g. 00/01/1900 all the way down column A).

Comment: @SachinKohli thank you for this. Not exactly sure how to use INDEX MATCH in this context.

Comment: Try `=@FILTER(Sheet2!A:F, Sheet2!G:G <>"ENDED","")` which will give you only first result. Use `@` operator if you do not want all the result.

Comment: That just leaves me with the heading. I need to be able to access all bookings for today. Can i add multiple conditions to a filter? E.G. <>"ENDED" & A:A = TODAY()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this formula:

```
=CHOOSECOLS(
     VSTACK(
           tblData[#Headers],
           FILTER(tblData,(tblData[Room]=Room)*(tblData[Date]=Date)*(tblData[Status]=""))),
  4,6,7)
```

I am using a table for the data (Insert > table) - this allows for more readable formulas :-)

I added two names `Date` (= your Sheet1!B1) and `Room`(= your Sheet1!H1)

If you want to returne other/more columns you have to adjust the parameters for `CHOOSECOLS` at the end of the formula.

[image]